# Can I install SQL Server 2008R2 SSMS without installing DB Engine instance?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a new development workstation and I need to install SSMS 2008R2 so I can connect to our network DB Server for work.  When I get to the feature selection page in the install, do I have to check DB Engine (instance)? Or can I just click the tools?  I have no need for a db instance on my machine, as all development will be on the db server.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197918(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Why do you ask? Did you encounter a problem when *unchecking* the Db Engine? Was something installed that you didn't expect?

Comment: No, I just don't see a reason to have a DB instance on my box when I will never create DBs in it.  But if I need it to make the tools work, then I would install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through the installation as if you would like to install a Sql Server instance. Once you reach the list with the items to be installed, uncheck Sql Server instance/service stuff, and just select the Management Tools.